# java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, credentials, google-text-to-speech

I am fairly new to GCP API functions.
I am currently trying to the use text-to-speech module following these steps: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries
I did not set up the environmental variable since I used the `authExplicit(String jsonPath)` for its authentication: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

my code looks like following;

```
public void main() throws Exception {
    String jsonPath = "/User/xxx/xxxx/xxxxxx/xxxx.json";
    authExplicit(jsonPath);
    //calling the text-to-speech function form the above link. 
    text2speech("some text");
}
```

authExplicit(jsonPath) goes through without any problem and prints a bucket. I thought the credential key in JSON was checked. However, text2speech function returns the error as follows:

```
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

I want to get the text2speech function work by call Google Cloud API functions.
Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Your advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's confusing.

[Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically) is a process that looks for the credentials in various places including the env var `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

If `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is unset **and** the code is running on a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Compute Engine (GCE) service (e.g. Compute Engine), then it use the Metadata service to determine the credentials. If not, ADC fails and raises an error.

Your code fails because, [`authExplicit`](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code) does not use ADC but loads the Service Account key from the file **and** creates a Storage account client using these credentials. Only the Storage client is thus authenticated.

I recommend a (simpler) solution: Use ADC and have Storage and Text2Speech clients both use ADC.

You will need to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var to the path to a key if you run your code **off** GCP (i.e. not on GCE or similar) but when it runs **on** GCP, it will leverage the service's credentials.

You will need to create both the Storage and Text2Speech clients to use ADCs:

See:

1. [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library)
2. [Text-to-Speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries#using_the_client_library)

```java
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
...
```

And:

```java
TextToSpeechClient textToSpeechClient = TextToSpeechClient.create()
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to set the environment variable as your guide. However it shows another error: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable. 
I am currently using android studio and the instruction provided google says that android is not supported. Can it cause this error?

Comment: Aha! I didn't realize you are using Android. I don't know how you use ADCs on Android. Hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: It worked as expected on intelliJ. apparently android studio cannot look into the environment variables.